# Can I add relatives as references in Indian passport renewal form?

Tags: indian-citizens, paperwork, passport-renewals

I want to be issued a new passport. In the application form I have to provide details for two references.

Can I add my relatives as references or those who do not live in the same city as I do?

Comment: Are there notes or guidelines on filling in the application form? What do they say about it?

Comment: Usually you will need to give the contacts of your neighbours as it helps during the time of PV. They may go to them and verify you.

Comment: Hi I am applying for my new passport and it asking me 2 reference but I do not have anyone so can I apply without reference or what can I do now ?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/112609)

Answer (score 2):

References are required for the authentication of the passport applicant during police verification.

A reference is a person who can vouch for the fact that you have stayed at the aforementioned address for the aforementioned period.

Hence, you cannot add people who don't live in the same city as you, as your reference. It would rather be preferable to use say, your friends'/neighbors'/employers' names as references.

As far as the relatives'names are concerned, the same applies to them too. I suppose you can use them as reference as long as they live in the same city.

Comment: During police verification, police sometimes insist that the referenced people should be under the same police station jurisdiction as the applicant. So adding names of people who are in the same city but under a different police station should be avoided.

Comment: "I suppose you can use [relatives] as reference" What do the actual regulations say? In the UK, I'm pretty sure you _can't_ use relatives as a reference, because they're felt to be more likely to lie on your behalf.